# Inviting players to Game Center via email

Tags: objective-c, ios6, game-center

I am developing a Turn-Based Game Center game and wonder if it is possible to invite players via email and not only players that all ready have the game and a user-id @ Game Center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn-based games powered by GameKit require Apple-ID centric invites. You can't programmatically invite a friend, which you would need to do if you were sending out email invites.

If you want to do email-based invites, you'll have to code your own solution and only use Game Center for things like achievements and leaderboards.

Comment: I guess it should be possible to generate an email from within the app with a link to the download page in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

To invite a player to an online multiplayer game using Game Center, the user must have a registered Apple ID. The user must also own the game to be able to accept, however I believe the user will still receive a notification in Game Center about the invite.

Comment: What if I skip the Game Center invitation and program the invitation, would it be possible to combine and schedule an email invitation?

Comment: You could send one out and see if there are magnet links for Game Center.